# 301 Redirect Regex Pattern - Sitecore Redirect module

Tags: regex, sitecore, redirect

I apologize if this seems like a rudimentary question, but I'm trying to setup a redirect pattern for the 301 module in Sitecore and am having a hard time with the proper pattern.

I need to have the following path:

`http://www.example.com/some-path/videos/2014/08/08/15/20/some-item-title`

converted to:
`http://www.example.com/some-path/videos/some-item-title`

Basically strip the numerical folders out.  How can I do that but preserve the beginning of the path and the item name at the end.

An https-safe version would be appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT**:

Note, the numerical folders are always in the above format: There is a 4 digit folder, followed by four, 2 digit folders.

`some-path/whatever/4444/22/22/22/22/item-name`

Comment: So you want the regex to match the whole link without `/2014/08/08/15/20`?

Comment: Yes, exactly.. and it's always in that format...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will fit your "less global" requirement.

```
var pattern = @"^(https?://[^/]*/some-path/videos/)\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}/(.*)$";
var match = Regex.Match(myurl, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var rewrittenUrl = string.Empty;
if (match.Success)
{
    rewrittenUrl = match.Groups[1].Value + match.Groups[2].Value;
}
```

Note that I chose to ignore case. This is probably correct behavior given that you are dealing with URLs. I edited the original post such that the pattern will match any host now.

Comment: awesome.. thanks.   That works well.  Just out of curiosity, if I didn't care about the subdomain/domain, what would it look like, so `http://DEV.example.com/....` or `https://TEST.example2.com/...` or `http://localhost/...` should still work.

Comment: I don't even think you should care about the http(s) part, since it's an internal redirect... Unless you are redirecting http traffic to http. You only care about the url path part.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex could be like that :

```
(https?:\/\/.*)\/\d{4}\/(\d{2}\/){4}(.*)
```

And your substitution :

```
$1/$3
```

It will preserve the https since the `s?` is an equivalent of `s{0,1}` in this case and this part is included in the first parentheses wrapped block.

Comment: That didn't seem to work.  Also, I was hoping for a less "global" solution... i only wanted it to happen for items under the `/some-path/videos/` path. I just want to delete the numerical paths, which are always in that format.  There is a 4 digit folder, followed by four, 2 digit folders.